# How to deal with Visual Studio IntelliSense complicating my LINQ expressions

Tags: visual-studio, linq, intellisense

I am using Visual studio 2022. Each time I try to type in a LINQ query

```
list = (from sale in sales)
```

after I start typing `from`, VS forces `FromBase64Transform` instead. As soon as I click space after `from`, it 'corrects' it to `FromBase64Transform`, so I have to go back to delete it.

My workaround is to type `fromsale` together, then go back and make a space between them.
As you can guess, this slows me down a lot.

How can IntelliSense be made to consider LINQ expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You can just press `Esc` key to cancel the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth, on my side, I didn't be able to reproduce this issue.

This is the code I am testing:

```
using Step2;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Step1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> sales = new() { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
            var list = (from sale in sales
                        where sale < 3 || sale > 7
                        select sale);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.Write(item+"\t");
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

And I can type the from of LINQ with no problem(type from, and press space, no problem.).

I think this issue may should comes from three reasons:

***1, the version of the VS Tools.***

The version of VS2022 on my side is 'Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.4.4'.

***2, the settings of VS Tools.***

Reset the language environment collection settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And to make sure not effected by the settings of the async user's settings, please [turn off the user settings async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#turn-off-synchronized-settings-on-a-particular-computer):

[image][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AiKm.png)

[image]

***3, some strange extensions***

Please check if there is some extensions that will affect this(In VS extension dialog or windows control panel.)

---

By the way, please share your minimal reproducible code if possible.